# What are some of the advantages and disadvantages of Explicit Semantic Analysis (ESA)?

Tags: latent-semantic-indexing

I am writing a report semantic analysis and I have come across a celebrated paper **Computing Semantic Relatedness using Wikipedia-based Explicit Semantic Analysis** by Evgeniy Gabrilovich and Shaul Markovitch.
I have been looking at this paper and some related articles but I couldn't find any important advantages or disadvantages of the approach.
Can someone help in looking at those?